# $2=1$ Paradoxes repository

Tags: big-list, fake-proofs, paradoxes

I really like to use paradoxes in my math classes, in order to awaken the interest of my students. Concretely, these last weeks I am proposing paradoxes that achieve the conclusion that **2=1**. After one week, I explain the solution in the blackboard and I propose a new one. For example, I posted the following one some months ago: [What is wrong with the sum of these two series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081892/what-is-wrong-with-the-sum-of-these-two-series)
I would like to increase my repertoire of fake-proofs. I would be glad to read your proposals and discuss them! My students are 18 years old, so don't be too cruel  :) Here is my own contribution:

\begin{equation}
y(x) = \tan x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime} = \frac{1}{\cos^{2} x}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime \prime} = \frac{2 \sin x}{\cos^{3} x}
\end{equation}
This can be rewritten as:
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime \prime} = \frac{2 \sin x}{\cos^{3} x} = \frac{2 \sin x}{\cos x \cdot \cos^{2} x} = 2 \tan x \cdot \frac{1}{\cos^{2} x} = 2yy^{\prime} = \left( y^{2} \right)^{\prime}
\end{equation}
Integrating both sides of the equation $y^{\prime \prime} = \left( y^{2} \right)^{\prime}$:
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime} = y^{2}
\end{equation}
And therefore
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\cos^{2} x} = \tan^{2} x
\end{equation}
Now, evalueting this equation at $x = \pi / 4$
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2}/2)^{2}} = 1^{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
2 = 1
\end{equation}

Comment: Cute. $2=1+C$ would be much less intresting.

Comment: Yes, when integrating this a a integration constant $C$. So we actually get 
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\cos^{2} x} = \tan^{2} x +C
\end{equation}
In fact $C=1$ and we correctly get $\frac{1}{\cos^{2} x} = 1+ \tan^{2} x $.

Comment: I think this is very cool: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417280/continued-fraction-fallacy-1-2/417322#417322

Comment: You may like this one: Proposition: There no such number $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Proof: Let us work by contradiction. Suposse there is  $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Then 
$$-i= (-1).i= i.i.i=\sqrt{-1}.\sqrt{-1}.\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{(-1).(-1).(-1)}=\sqrt{-1}=i $$
So $i=0$.  But, clearly $0^2 =0\neq -1$, so $0$ cannot be equal to $\sqrt{-1}$. Contradiction.

Comment: @Ant  There are many forms to present Paradoxes. One of them is to present a proof of something we know to be false. We know that there is a complex number $i$.  So the "proposition" in my coment above is false. However, the proof (at a naive first sight) may look correct.

Comment: @Ramiro To make it officially fit the challenge, multiply both sides of $i=0$ by $i$ and add $2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas while $\exists_C 2 = 1 + C$ the error is already earlier in $2yy' \neq 2(y^2)'$. Taking $y = x$: $2(x^2)' = 4x \neq 2x = 2 x 1$.

Comment: @PyRulez  You are right, just to force the conclusion  2=1. However, in my comment, I was considering a slightly broader approach of  "paradoxes" that might be useful for teaching. In the way I presented, some students MAY find it more intriguing and not so obviously wrong.

Comment: @Ramiro actually, I misread! Apologies ;-)

Answer (score 12):

One of my favorites, and very simple to understand for most algebra students:

$2 = 1+1$

$2 = 1+\sqrt{1}$

$2 = 1+\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}$

$2 =^* 1+\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}$

$2 = 1+i*i$

$2 = 1+i^2$

$2 = 1+(-1)$

$2 = 0$

$^*$ *The wrong step*

Divide both sides by 2 and add 1 and you would get $2=1$, as you desired.

---

To be thorough, the mistake occurs in the fourth line where the square root is split. In reality, the rule is:

$\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ when either $a\geq0$ or $b\geq0$

$\sqrt{ab}=-\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ when $a<0$ and $b<0$

So you would have an equality if you follow that rule, but many students aren't going to catch the error.

Comment: Why the $1+$ in each step? Seems like it would be cleaner if you "prove" $1=-1$ in the main part and then use linearity to turn it into $2=1$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro, that's certainly true. I just relayed it here the way I first saw it. I imagine the appeal at first was "two is nothing?!" You could, of course, use this to "prove" any number equals zero.

Answer (score 10):

$$0 = (1-1)+(1-1)+ … = 1 -(1-1)-(1-1)-… = 1 \implies 2=1$$

Comment: This is why we should always use sigma notation ;)

Answer (score 6):

Why not show all numbers are equal to 1:

For any $z\in\mathbb R$,
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}z^{n}=z\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}z^{n-1}=z\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}z^{n}.
$$
So 
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}z^{n}=z\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}z^{n}\Rightarrow 1=z.
$$

Comment: The correct conclusion, of course, is $\sum_nz^n=0$. :P

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Or undefined

Comment: Yeah, my last comment was me joking. It _is_ undefined.

Comment: $\sum_{n\geq 0}z^n$ and $\sum_{n<0}z^n$ have complementary regions of convergence, but each sum admits analytic continuation and the sum of the continuations is $0$.

Answer (score 5):

Another enjoyable "paradox": We first denote
$$S:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$
The fact that $0\neq S\in\mathbb R$ can be established using elementary tools.
We then write: 
$S=\frac{1}{1}-\frac {1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-...+...-...$
$2S = 2(\frac{1}{1}-\frac {1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-...+...-...)=\frac{2}{1}-\frac {2}{2}+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{4}+\frac{2}{5}-\frac{2}{6}+\frac{2}{7}-...=$ 
$=\color{red}{\frac{2}{1}}\color{red}{-\frac {2}{2}}\color{green}{+\frac{2}{3}}\color{blue}{-\frac{2}{4}}+\frac{2}{5}\color{green}{-\frac{2}{6}}+\frac{2}{7}-...=\color{red}{\frac{1}{1}}\color{blue}{-\frac{1}{2}}\color{green}{+\frac{1}{3}}-...=S$

And at last:
$$2S = S \Longrightarrow 2=1$$

Comment: This is that rearrangement theorem, right? The one that says that any convergent sequence can be rearranged to converge to any value?

Comment: @FarazMasroor Yes, this is an abuse of Riemann series theorem (Rearrangement theorem).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple one:

$$
x=y\\
x^2=xy\\
2x^2=x^2+xy\\
2x^2-2xy=x^2-xy\\
2(x^2-xy)=1(x^2-xy)\\
2=1
$$

The error is quite obviously division by zero (from the 5th to 6th step).

Answer (score 5):

$x = \underbrace{1 + 1 + 1 + \ldots + 1}_{x \textrm{ times}} = \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x\right) + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x\right) + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x\right) + \ldots + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x\right)}_{x \textrm{ times}} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\underbrace{\left(x + x + x + \ldots + x\right)}_{x \textrm{ times}} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x^2\right) = 2x$

Comment: Beat me to it! Of course if you use the "chain rule" you get
$$\frac{d}{dx}\underbrace{x+x+\cdots+x}_{x\ \mathrm{times}} = \underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{x\ \mathrm{times}} + \underbrace{x+x+\cdots+x}_{1\ \mathrm{times}}$$
which works!

Answer (score 4):

Does this count or is it too obvious where things go wrong, considering there is only one step?

Define $f_n(x) = n \cdot 1_{x \le \frac 1n}$

Clearly for every $x$, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$$

Therefore

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)\  dx = \int_0^1 0 \ dx = 0$$

But $\int_0^1 f_n(x) \ dx = 1$ for every $n$; hence it is proved that

$$1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 = 0$$

Comment: Could you please explain where is the flaw? I think it's because $f_n(x)$  doesn't converge uniformly to $0$, but I can't see why it doesn't.

Comment: @Alnitak The problem is that you cannot bring the limit under the integral sign. In fact, lebesgue dominated convergence theorem doesn't apply; and, as you say, $f_n$ does not converge uniformly. In fact, $$sup |f_n(x) - f(x)| = n \not \to 0$$

Answer (score 4):

Here's one I just made up. $\log_{b} b^x = x$. And $\log_{b} 1 = 0$.

Let $b = 1, x = 1$, and $b^x = 1$.  Then $0 = \log_b 1 = \log_b b^x = x = 1$

Comment: I can't see why $\log_b b^x = x.\log_{b} 1$

Comment: Those are two separate sentences.  $\log_b b^x = x$.  And $\log_b 1= 0$.

Answer (score 4):

In the same vein as your example, let's integrate $\frac1x$ by parts.

Let $I = \int\frac1x\ \textrm dx$, and set $u = \frac1x, \textrm dv = \textrm dx$. Then:

$$
\begin{align}
I = \int u\ \textrm dv &= uv - \int v\ \textrm du \\
&= \frac1x\cdot x - \int x\left(\frac{-1}{x^2}\right) \textrm dx \\
&= 1 + \int\frac1x\ \textrm dx \\
&= 1 + I
\end{align}
$$

Therefore $0 = 1$, so clearly $1 = 2$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one of my favorites.

> **Proof that $1=0$**
>
> Let's consider for real $x$ the function $f(x)=xe^{-x^2}$. Note, the following integral representation of $f$ is valid (substitute: $u=x^2/y$).
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^3}{y^2}e^{-x^2/y}\,dy
> =\left[xe^{-x^2/y}\right]_0^1
> =xe^{-x^2}
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain for all $x$ the following relationship
>
> \begin{align*}
> e^{-x^2}(1-2x^2)&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(xe^{-x^2}\right)\\
> &=\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1\frac{x^3}{y^2}e^{-x^2/y}\,dy\\
> &=\int_0^1\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{x^3}{y^2}e^{-x^2/y}\right)\,dy\\
> &=\int_0^1e^{-x^2/y}\left(\frac{3x^2}{y^2}-\frac{2x^4}{y^3}\right)\,dy
> \end{align*}
>
> and observe by setting $x=0$ the left-hand side is one while the right-hand side is zero.
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{LHS: }\qquad e^0(1-0)&=1\\
> \text{RHS: }\qquad \int_0^1 0\,dy&=0
> \end{align*}

**Note:** This example can be found in *[Counterexamples in Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486428753)* by B.R. Gelbaum and J.H.M. Holmsted.

Answer (score 3):

$(1 - x)(1 + x + x^2 + ..... )=$

$(1 + x + x^2 .... )(-x - x^2 - x^3 -......)  = 1 + (x -x) + (x^2 - x^2)... = 1$ so

$1 + x + x^2 + .... = \frac{1}{1 - x}$

Let x = -1.

$ 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 .... = \frac{1}{1 -(-1)} = \frac 12$

but clearly $1 - 1 + 1 - 1 +... = (1-1) + (1-1) +... = 0$.

So $0 = \frac 12$ (and also 1, and -1).

Answer (score 3):

Although it's not quite what you're looking for, the [Banach-Tarski paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox) shows that, in a certain sense, $1$ does equal $2$:

Given a solid ball in $\mathbb R^3$, there is a way to decompose the ball into $5$ disjoint sets, move them by rigid motions, and obtain two solid balls of the same radius.

The catch is that these are non-measurable sets (and, of course, you need the Axiom of Choice).

Comment: You can make this a "proper" $1=2$ proof by measuring the final sets (which are measurable). We can find sets $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2,B_3$ such that $A_1\cup A_2=B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3=S$ and $A_1'\cup A_2'\cup B_1'\cup B_2'\cup B_3'=S$ (where $S$ is a sphere of measure $1$ and all the unions are disjoint, and the primes indicate euclidean transformations); then $$1=\mu(S)=(\mu(A_1)+\mu(A_2))+(\mu(B_1)+\mu(B_2)+\mu(B_3))=\mu(S)+\mu(S)=2.$$ (Of course the stuff involving $\mu(A_1)$ is nonsense, but it looks plausible.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=(x_{ij})$ be the infinite matrix (where omitted entries are $0$), $$x = \begin{pmatrix}1  \\ -1 & 1 \\ &-1 & 1 \\ &&-1 & 1\\ &&&\ddots&
\end{pmatrix}$$
i.e. $x_{ij} = \Bbb 1_{i=j} - \Bbb 1_{i=j+1}$. Here $i$ is the row, $j$ is the column.
Then $$∑_{ij} x_{ij}=∑_i\left(∑_jx_{ij}\right) = ∑_i0 = 0$$
While also
$$∑_{ij} x_{ij}=∑_j\left(∑_ix_{ij}\right) = ∑_j\Bbb 1_{j=1} = 1$$

So $1=2$.

---

For the interested, this is a violation of Fubini.

Comment: Note: This is just a restatement of http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1480519/50776 in new language.

Answer (score 2):

I always liked the one that "proves" $1+2+3+4+...=1/12$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Answer (score 1):

Let $U_n$ be a probability measure on $[0,1]$ such that when restricted to $\{0,\frac{1}{n},…,\frac{n-1}{n},1\}$, is the uniform measure on that set. i.e.
$$ U_n\left( A \right) := \left| \left\{ k∈{0,…,n} : \frac{k}{n} ∈ A\right\}\right|$$

Of course, as you send $n→∞$, $U_n$ tends to the (continuous) uniform measure on $[0,1], U_{[0,1]}$,
$$U_n→ U_{[0,1]}$$
Note that if $Q=\Bbb Q∩ [0,1]$, $Q$ is measurable and $U_{[0,1]}$-null, so
$$1 = U_n(Q) → U_{[0,1]}(Q) = 0$$
Hence  $2=1$.